# I want to be able to search across 2 different models in flask_sqlachemy python

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

[image: pic of my code]This is what I have come up with so far but only the first function work I want to be able to combine both functions into a single function so that I can search both student and teacher models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single function store the results of queries in two different list called
res1=Teacher.query()
res2=Student.query()

Then use,
result=res1+res2

Comment: thanks very much i spent an entire day trying to fix this and the solution was so simple lol

Comment: @Speedster Yes, its better to know properties of some data structures in python and do print intermediate results which could help you debug or improve your code. Do upvote teh answer if it solved your problem :))

Comment: hey, it solved the problem with the search but another issue came up when I implemented a delete function in that it deletes records that have the same ID number. I tried using contact as another way but didn't work.. any suggestion

Comment: @Speedster For deleting maintain two different list for student and teacher, Like:  Ids={"teacher": [2,3,4,5],"Students":[1,2,3,4]} and delete accordingly. Since both table could have similar ID's

Comment: @Speedster Can you give the context. How do you know who's id to delete, whether students or teachers. If there is other info to support delete, use <int:id>/<s> where s says whether its student or teacher.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tRP9Ef2TcPoNktTFGUwENl7xzaPRcOP6/view?usp=sharing    this is my function.. the way how I learnt it is by passing the data into the function it removes the record.. so the way I have it set up is if the user click the select button it passes the ID of the record the function which them pull the record from the database and delete

Comment: @Speedster Without any information other than ID we can't distinguish between Student and Teacher. So you can use other variable like <int:id>/<int:s> where s =0 means its teacher else its student. So in the front end you need to know whether its teacher or student and then call the app along with <int:s> which says whether its teacher or student. If you still have doubt, drop your mail id, I would connect through gmail chat.

Comment: thanks bro, I finally figure it out. what I did was added a secret default value to the model column then I use an if statement to decide which model to query based on that secret value 0 or 1 call the desired model